Using window.addEventListener beforeinstallprompt, it may occasionally not be triggered when the page is refreshed dozens of times。
My pwa project was successfully launched, using the following code:
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e => {
  console.log('Show pwa button')
  state.buttonShow=true // The default value is false
  e.preventDefault()
  window.deferredPrompt = e
})

I use this code to determine whether the pwa button is displayed。(The default value is false)
The development process went smoothly and there were no problems.
However, after going online, I found that in the window Google Chrome browser, I forced to refresh the page several times, and refreshed it dozens of times, and occasionally the button would not be displayed. The console did not print "Show pwa button".
So I think there is an occasional problem with the browser's monitoring? My project is vue3, and the above code is placed in app.vue.
I'd really appreciate if someone could answer this, thank you very much!

First of all, it's an experimental feature. Check out the browser compatibility. Second of all, if you discovered the behavior is inconsistent in a particular browser, the best thing to do is open an issue on their repo, providing a runnable [mcve] and hope they'll fix it, although I wouldn't expect a fix sooner than 6 months, if it's indeed a browser issue, which we can't know without a runnable example.

The browser supports Google Chrome version 127.0.6533.119 (official version). It can be displayed normally, but after refreshing dozens of times, it will occasionally appear without triggering.
